# Collapse sections in markdown

Tags: writing, markdown, markdown-mode, outline

I use `markdown-mode` (in conjunction with `writeroom-mode`) for writing in Emacs. My markdown files generally gets quite large, and I would like to be able to focus on a particular section for extended periods of time.

How can I achieve this? Specifically I'm looking to hide or collapse other sections (heading and their text) while working on the current one. http://www.foldingtext.com behaves in this manner.

Comment: My ten-seconds not-thought-out answer is: does it work with hideshow mode? https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hideshow.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With [markdown-mode by Jason Blevins](http://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/) you can toggle folding of the heading with <kbd>Tab</kbd> (same as in org-mode).

Comment: True (+1). However, with `emacs -nw`, it turns out that you want to use `Shift + Tab` to get things to fold. (Which I only mention because I only found out by accident that this works....)

Comment: Also, `C-x n d` will `narrow` to the current section*, and -- importantly -- `C-x n w` *undoes* this by running `widen`.  *** via `narrow-to-defun`, which is `markdown-mode` is mapped to `markdown-narrow-to-section`.  You can type `C-x n s` to run `markdown-narrow-to-section`, which is directly what you want, but since `C-x n d` does what you want and is useful in other modes, I prefer to use that for better muscle-memory-applicability.

Answer (score 3):

I've found two ways that can be useful:

1. enable hideshow mode (hs-minor-mode) and use the provided functions
2. Apparently markdown-mode inherits from outline mode (or at least the functions are available here!) so you can use functions like hide-subtree and show-subtree.